# Periodically send captured image javascript webrtc

Tags: javascript, post, browser, camera, webrtc

How to make a POST request periodically?

I used the instruction from https://davidwalsh.name/browser-camera and it is working.

Jay left the comment there in which he sends image using POST request but I still can not use it in my code.

```
navigator.webkitGetUserMedia({video:true},function(stream){
        document.getElementById("video").src = webkitURL.createObjectURL(stream);
    },
    ....

    var video_element = document.getElementById('video'); 
    var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d"); 
    ctx.drawImage(video_element,0, 0, 640,480, 0,0, 320,240);
    ....
var data = imgData.substr(22); 
$.post(qurl,{ 'dataImg' : data ,   ...
```

How can I adopt this code to send an image every 10 seconds and check whether the previous image was sent or not?

Answer (score 1):

Try This Code

```js
var video = document.getElementById('video');

// Get access to the camera!
if(navigator.mediaDevices && navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
    // Not adding `{ audio: true }` since we only want video now
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true }).then(function(stream) {
        video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
        video.play();
    });
}

// Elements for taking the snapshot
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var video = document.getElementById('video');

// Trigger photo take
setTimeout(autoclick, 1000);
functio autoclick(){
  document.getElementById("snap").addEventListener("click", function() {
    context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 640, 480);
  });
  var imgData = context.getImageData(0, 0, 640, 480);
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/imgupload',
    data: {'file':imgData},
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function (data) {
       // action
    }
});
}
```

```html
<video id="video" width="640" height="480" autoplay></video>
<button id="snap">Snap Photo</button>
<canvas id="canvas" width="640" height="480"></canvas>
```

Comment: Request payload is [object Object]

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap that code in a function, then you can call it periodically by using the 'setInterval' method.

```
setInterval(myCaptureImageFunction , 10000);
```

It will run your function every 10 seconds.

With regards to checks, you can create a variable that stores the last successful upload details (including time), and then just query that variable or print it out as a status message.

Here is a link to the documentation for 'setInterval': https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp